# Provisioning Windows 8/10 tablets

Tags: windows, provisioning, laptop

How do you automate the deployment of software and configuration (users etc) on tablets?

The context is a number of [Linx](http://linxtablets.com/) and Surface tablets that will be sent out to sites where they will be put on a LAN without internet access. We don't need or want remote management or AD, we just want to do one-time setup. And then later potentially reformat/reinstall any units that are returned as faulty.

Previously, for regular PCs, we've made sysprepped disk images using volume license keys for Windows 7, but you can't physically pull and reimage disks on tablets and we haven't arranged any Win10 volume license keys. We would like to continue using the licenses that ship with the tablets.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provide a business targeted version of their store which will allow you to provision and manage software for the tablet OS

windows 10 provides built in functionality for reverting the system to its original state.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/business-store/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options

Comment: The store looks interesting, but presumably that's only for Metro/UWP apps and not "legacy" Win32 apps? And can it be used to create new user accounts, set passwords etc on the device?

Comment: sorry i thought you were referring to metro apps - with regards to configuring accounts and passwords and deploying win32 apps i believe you could do this with powershell DSC if you don't want to use AD/group policy, create the script and stick your installers somewhere locally, i guess another partition would be best so you can still use system restore.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to slipstream things into the system restore partition? So I could have our powershell run at the end of the restore process.

Comment: Probably, theres the Full MDT kit that lets you create unattend files for deployment, not something i have tried but its a pretty comprehensive set of tools